# Different Margin property value of ContentPresenter depending on theme (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have no idea how to set fixed value to `Margin` property of a `ContentPresenter` in `XAML`.

I am using Telerik WPF library to switch UI themes. Everything looks good so far but when I
switch to a theme (Visual Studio 2013 theme), the content of a button becomes too small.

When I investigated with the `Snoop` tool, the theme internally changes the Margin property of `ContentPresenter` to big value, then the content size gets small as a result.

Is there a way to fix the `Margin` property value of `ContentPresenter` to my own (for instance, fix the value to 3) without using `ControlTemplate` block in my code? (such as ... Style setter of `ContentPresenter.Margin`...)

The following code is actually what I want, though I should not use the `ControlTemplate` block in my code...

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid Background="Green">
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,260 L0,600 L110,670 L110,500 L190,550 L190,710 L300,775 L300,430 L150,175">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="50" LineJoin="Round" Brush="Red"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    </DrawingBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="3"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: did you try setting a default style for `ContentPresenter`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an implicit style by specifying a `TargetType`, but no `x:Key`.

For example, the following should make the `Margin` property equal to 3 in any `ContentPresenter` inside the `Window`, unless another property setter has a higher [DependencyPropertyPrecedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

If there are aspects of the base style you want to preserve, you can use the `BasedOn` style property to inherit all other properties from the base style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentPresenter}}">
```

or

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyleKey}">
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thanks for your comment. It's really helpful! But... can I give me any idea about why the Margin doesn't work in following code?

 <Button>
   <Button.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
   </Style>
  </Button.Resources>
  <Button.Content>
   <StackPanel Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="This is a TextBlock in Button."/>
   </StackPanel>
  </Button.Content>
 </Button>

The cursor has been changed to Hand. it's good though the Margin doesn't seem to be changed...